# ruby method caching performance

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I'm using the cache_method gem, and while profiling some critical process in my app I found the following result

```
 6.11    0.01    0.00    6.10    413/413    ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache#write_entry  364
 4.70    0.01    0.00    4.69    388/388    ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache#delete_entry
```

Is it possible that for 413 cache write and 388 cache delete it takes 10 seconds?
sound way too much. Any way to improve this with some configuration options?

Comment: if it is really critical, you can always write an C extension to ruby.

Comment: I don't want to maintain c code thanks

Comment: Is this cache shared between processes? Maybe compare it to simple memoization.

Comment: I dont know I just used the method caching gem

Comment: What are the column headings for your output? It is important to distinguish between inclusive and exclusive time when profiling. For instance, if the cache_write routine is yielding to your code to generate the cached contents, then it would not be too surprising to see a large time for 413 calls to the routine you want to cache.

Comment: @ChenKinnrot: the performance differences between the various Markdown implementations ought to give you pause.

Comment: When I remove method cache and use the mongoid quey cache, it works super fast,I guess my calculation arent complex enough for method caching with this specific gem.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly possible that these operations take so long to achieve, the first symptom is indexing, while updating your cache you are certainly updating your indexes and this is the heaviest task in caching mechanism.
You can take a look in your index configuration, and depending in its implementation you can use lazy index refresh to avoid latency in Delete and Update operations.
Cheers